# dict() function behaves differently between colab and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Google's colab and jupyter notebook reacts differently to the `dict()` function

**Jupyter Notebook:**

```
!python --version
Python 3.7.6
```

code:

```
trial=[(1, 250), (3, 275), (5, 290), (2, 300), (4, 500)]
dict(trial)
```

output:

```
{1: 250, 3: 275, 5: 290, 2: 300, 4: 500}
```

**Google Colab:**

```
!python --version
Python 3.6.9
```

code:

```
trial=[(1, 250), (3, 275), (5, 290), (2, 300), (4, 500)]
dict(trial)
```

output:

```
{1: 250, 2: 300, 3: 275, 4: 500, 5: 290}
```

Why do you think there is a difference like that, can it also be a version problem?

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#summary-release-highlights) onwards, dictionaries maintain the order of keys to be the same as their order of insertion, so to answer your question, yes, it's because of the version.

The idea was proposed from python3.6 onwards, but it was still considered [implementation dependent](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict):

> The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon (this may change in the future, but it is desired to have this new dict implementation in the language for a few releases before changing the language spec to mandate order-preserving semantics for all current and future Python implementations; this also helps preserve backwards-compatibility with older versions of the language where random iteration order is still in effect, e.g. Python 3.5).

From Python 3.7, this requirement was mandatory and elevated to be a language specification.

Answer (score 0):

Google colab python is now version 3.7.12 and the behaviour is still the same so the answer by @Jarvis is incorrect.

Google colab python stores the dict internally in the correct order and when displayed using the print function uses the correct order. However, using colab to display the value of the last expression in a cell, it sorts dict by keys. My advice is to always use print() function.

code:

```
trial=[(1, 250), (3, 275), (5, 290), (2, 300), (4, 500)]
dct_trial = dict(trial)
print(dct_trial)
dct_trial
```

output: (notice how the order is different)

```
{1: 250, 3: 275, 5: 290, 2: 300, 4: 500}
{1: 250, 2: 300, 3: 275, 4: 500, 5: 290}
```